# How can I slow down a video (which I use as wallpaper) so it will look more realistic?

Tags: video-editing, desktop-customization

I have an `.mpg` file of the Earth spinning. I use it as a background/wallpaper for my desktop.  However, it spins too fast.

How can I slow it down?

Comment: Please stop editing every single question on this site. it'

Comment: Editing is a part of this site. You don't really need the "Thanks in advance"; it's rather superfluous.  If you want to be a member of this site, you'll have to get used to people editing your posts.

Comment: Please check out the [faq](http://superuser.com/faq#editing) under **Other people can edit my stuff?!**

Comment: If you want it to be realistic, you'll need 24 hours per rotation.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Windows Live Movie Maker.  Import the video into the program, then go to the "Video Tools" tab.  There will be a box where you can adjust the speed of the video.  Then you can just save the movie and you'll be done.

Comment: Thank you. That did it well. It's not as smooth as the original is, but I don't think I can get it better because of how the original was done in the first place.

Comment: Always glad to help. :)